# Even though the argument of function is the same, the error "Warning: Declaration of… should be compatible with" is output

Tags: php, symfony

As shown below, the following error occurred while updating the service argument.
As for the work I did, I put `EcArticleDataService $ecArticleDataService` and `AnalyticsService $analyticsService` in each function and `$this->get('...')` was converted to an argument. I also added a route with use.
Did I make a mistake in dealing with something?

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html

Error

```
Warning: Declaration of App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Hq\AnalyticsController::articleAction 
(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request,   
App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Hq\EcArticleDataService $ecArticleDataService,  
App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\AnalyticsService $analyticsService) should be compatible with  
App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\BaseAnalyticsController::articleAction  
(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request, 
App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\EcArticleDataService $ecArticleDataService, 
App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\AnalyticsService $analyticsService)
```

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\EcStaffDataService;
use App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\AnalyticsService;
class BaseAnalyticsController extends BaseController
{
    public function articleAction(Request $request, EcArticleDataService $ecArticleDataService, AnalyticsService $analyticsService)
    {
     ...
    }
```

AnalyticsController.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\AnalyticsService;
use App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\EcStaffDataService;

class AnalyticsController extends BaseAnalyticsController
{
    public function articleAction(Request $request, EcArticleDataService $ecArticleDataService, AnalyticsService $analyticsService)
    {
        return parent::articleAction($request, $ecArticleDataService, $analyticsService);
    }
```

Comment: They're not the same. Read the error message *carefully*. One version has `App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Controller\Hq\EcArticleDataService` and the other `App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\EcArticleDataService`. My guess - you forgot a `use` statement in one of those two. Or perhaps both.

Comment: @El_Vanja I made a silly mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As El_Vanja says, it was because I didn't add the route to the Analytics Controller.
I added the following to solve the problem.

```php
use App\Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Service\EcArticleDataService;
```